# Washing machine tap is seized, what can I try?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, washing-machine

As I was trying to install a first washing machine at my folks new home, I ran into the issue of not being able to open the water line into the machine. Context: the bathroom went through a refurbishment and no washing machine has ever been connected there. Obviously I assumed the tap was closed (no running water) hence tried turning counter clockwise but the tap would not nudge. The tap being plastic (and felt prone to breaking if more force was used). I removed the plastic 'head' to check for corrosion or seizing and saw this:

[image]
[image]
[image]
<sup>Click to embiggen</sup>

I tried turning it with a spanner in both directions to no help. I want to apply some anti-seize and try again.

- What do you advise?
- Does it look like a new tap altogether is needed?

I don't have any contact info to the workers who did the refurbishment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That big nut around the black stem holds the stem in place. Try loosening that nut slightly. Maybe just 1/2 turn, and see if it allows the stem to turn. If it does, Great!   now be sure water is not leaking around the nut or stem when the water is on.
If that is not successful, turn off the water to the house, open another tap to relieve the pressure and remove the big nut. That should allow you to unscrew and remove the stem and see if there is something binding or sticking. If you cannot remove the stem at that point, the entire tap must be replaced.

Comment: You should turn off the water to the house before trying to loosen the nut.

Comment: Can anyone share a video showing how the whole tap needs to be well setup? I am new at (minor) plumbing tasks

Comment: So I have just given it a shot: loosening the gold bolt for 1/2 or more did not help looseing the stem. I did cut the water and removed the bolt entirely, but there I did not know how to remove the stem, is it supposed to unscrew entirely when turning the square head?

Comment: Fyi even when free from the bolt I see the square head of the stem deforming under torque without turning, and I stop there